# How to load s3 csv gz file to Redshift in Copy commd with backslash character

Tags: scala, amazon-redshift

one s3 file is *.csv.gz, it delimter as comma, but some rows have some special words.

CSV file data sample:
doc_key,doc_name,doc_brand,brand_inc,etl_load_date
8a14eff760993c84d2306b3547fc6bea,VIRTUALLY CALIFORNIA,UNITED STATES OF AMERICA,UNKNOWN,2018-02-28
1fd23373942c9ffcdfc7223cd1114ee1,"ARIZONA \"9\" LLC",UNITED STATES OF AMERICA,UNKNOWN,2018-02-28

copy stg.train_ticket from 's3://{path}/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={aws_access_key_id};aws_secret_access_key={aws_secret_access_key}'
TRIMBLANKS TRUNCATECOLUMNS ACCEPTINVCHARS dateformat as 'auto' 
GZIP csv quote as '"' delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER as 1;

I ran the copy cmd on sqlworkbench and get error:
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
copy stg.train_ticket from 's3://{path}/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={aws_access_key_id};aws_secret_access...

Amazon Invalid operation: Load into table 'train_ticket ' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.;
1 statement failed.

Checked this table stl_load_errors and detailed error info:
column: doc_name
err_reason: Invalid quote formatting for CSV
raw_field_value: ARIZONA \
err_code: 1214

Could anyone please help take a look how to escape the backslash?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping it with another backslash.
i.e. replace `\word` with `\\word`

Answer (score 0):

You use some regex or escaping configurations to correct you data, if you can't do it at all fully use following option in your Copy command.

MAXERROR XXXXX(some X number less then 1,00,000).
e.g

```
 copy stg.train_ticket from 's3://{path}/' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={aws_access_key_id};aws_secret_access_key={aws_secret_access_key}' TRIMBLANKS TRUNCATECOLUMNS ACCEPTINVCHARS dateformat as 'auto' GZIP csv quote as '"' delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER as 1 MAXERROR as 10000;
```

This will enable you to continue loading your data, refer [following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) Amazon RedShift documentation for more information. Though this is quick fix and eventually you have to put some logic in place that will correct your data escaping issues.